# Typescript error TS1005 in create-react-app --typescript default files

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm just starting to learn React and Typescript, so I'm trying to understand the basics from the React documentation and I'm running into this error when I npm start. Not sure why I'm getting an error in the create-react-app default files. I'm using the latest typescript version. Thanks for any help in advance!

[image]

Comment: Same question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60856081/create-react-app-with-typescript-template-failed-to-compile

Comment: Thank you @keikai I will keep an eye on that thread