# create-react-app error import type * as PrettyFormat from './types' in pretty-format

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

it's a fresh install of cra with typescript template running on node 13.11.0 it gives me error when try to run npm start

````
TypeScript error in D:/Projects/personal-site/node_modules/@types/testing-library__react/node_modules/pretty-format/build/index.d.ts(7,13):
'=' expected.  TS1005

     5 |  * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
     6 |  */
  >  7 | import type * as PrettyFormat from './types';
       |             ^
     8 | /**
     9 |  * Returns a presentation string of your `val` object
    10 |  * @param val any potential JavaScript object```
````

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Update

Thanks for [marcelo-waisman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322442/marcelo-waisman)'s post.

#### Upgrading Typescript to > 3.8.0 solved this.

If we follow the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) tightly...

```
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

... we should have installed TypeScript with the latest version, rather than the local-global version which may still below 3.8.0.

---

I found some clues. Maybe it's worth an opening an issue.

It's related to the package `pretty-format` and its type in `create-react-app`.
We can find the source here: [pretty-format/src/index.ts](https://github.com/SimenB/jest/blob/b68f26780310df0c88ca349ff8a06ef4dc328c2e/packages/pretty-format/src/index.ts)

```
import style = require('ansi-styles');
import type * as PrettyFormat from './types';
```

From the commit history, we can see there is a related [Pull Request](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/9693) from two days ago, which changed this part from...

```
import * as PrettyFormat from './types';
```

... to...

```
import type * as PrettyFormat from './types';
```

This seems to be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 8):

Actually this "import type" is a new syntax introduced in Typescript 3.8
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-exports

The solution is actually very simple (if it's an option for you), just upgrade your typescript to 3.8+

Comment: Yes, manually update the typescript version solves this issue.