# React app build failed for popper js typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, popperjs

I have react app that used bootstrap 4.3.1 as node modules.When i am building the app its giving below error `TypeScript error in /codebuild/output/src478180495/src/app-name/node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.d.ts(1,13): '=' expected.  TS1005 > 1 | import type { OptionsGeneric, Modifier, Instance, VirtualElement } from "./types";` It was fine earlier. error coming up today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is due to a new syntax introduced by Typescript [type-only-imports-and-export](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#-type-only-imports-and-export)

Upgrade your `typescript` module in `package.json` to > 3.8.0 and `@type` definitions should solve this issue.

Heres the related [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60856373/10488576) topic.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem while coding a web part for SPFx, which is slightly different, but since search led me here, so I'll leave the answer for anyone in the future.

while updated typescript to 4.4 when running `gulp serve` i got `typescript version: 3.7.7`. Steps to remedy:

1. run `npm i @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9` This variant selects TypeScript 3.9
2. in `tsconfig.json` change `extends` to `"extends": "./node_modules/@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9/includes/tsconfig-web.json",`
3. in `tslint.json` remove `"no-use-before-declare": true,` as it will cause error `Error - [tslint] no-use-before-declare is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.`